# How to overlay a color image with a boolean mask and a boolean label (numpy)

Tags: python, image-processing

I would like please to display and image(RGB).shape(A,B,3) with its label (boolean array).shape(A,B) and its mask (boolean array).shape(A,B).

image:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azlGb.png)

label : [Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKrML.png)

Mask :[Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2U3h.png)

Actually, I need to apply the mask to the main image and its label and overlay the result. The main image is an RGB one (3D array). On the other side, the mask and the label are boolean 2D array.

Thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Actually, I need to apply the mask to the main image and its label and overlay the result. The main image is an RGB one (3D array). On the other side, the mask and the label are boolean 2D array.

Comment: @user6390975 `label3 = np.stack([label, label, label], axis=2)` then simply multiply them: `result = img * label3`